# How do I put sketch information in an .inp file from abaqus?

Tags: abaqus

I want to read the sketch information in the .inp file.
But it is not in there.
It exists only in the .cae file.
Can I put that information in the .inp file?
If you know how, please let me know.
I'll be waiting for your answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you give some examples? The problem is not clear, because of course you can put information to the .inp file: just open it in any text redactor or use python, or bash or something else.

Comment: I use abaqus in isight. However, if the dat file is used as output in isight, the cae file cannot be used as input. I want to use the variable as the sketch value. So I have to put the sketch information in the inf file. This is how you read the sketch information. 
'Model_1__Part__Solid_extrude_1_dimension{0}_sketch' Is this possible?

Comment: Never used isight, so I don't understand what you are talking about. Give some examples and maybe someone could help you, at the moment there is not enough information to answer your question. Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)